# Why am I getting an access violation when trying to convert bytes array to class instance with Marshal.PtrToStructure?

Tags: .net, byte, structure, marshalling

In C++, I have this:

```
struct BasePacketProto
{
    unsigned short PACKET_OPCODE;
    unsigned short PACKET_MAGIC_NUMBER;
    unsigned short PACKET_REMAIN_DATA_LENGTH;
};

struct CM_Request_AcceptAccount : BasePacketProto
{
    unsigned char ACCOUNT_LOGIN[16];
    unsigned char ACCOUNT_PASSWORD[16];
};

static void SendPacket()
{
    CM_Request_AcceptAccount packet;
    packet.PACKET_OPCODE = opCM_Request_AcceptAccount;
    packet.PACKET_MAGIC_NUMBER = 123;
    packet.PACKET_REMAIN_DATA_LENGTH = sizeof(CM_Request_AcceptAccount) -
                                       sizeof(BasePacketProto);
    memcpy(packet.ACCOUNT_LOGIN, "asd", sizeof("asd") * sizeof(char));
    memcpy(packet.ACCOUNT_PASSWORD, "asd_pass", sizeof("asd_pass") * sizeof(char));

    //Send the packet to the server.
    int lLength = send(lhSocket, (const char*)&packet, sizeof(CM_Request_AcceptAccount), 0);
}
```

In [C#](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29), this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
class BasePacketProto
{
    public System.UInt16 PACKET_OPCODE;
    public System.UInt16 PACKET_MAGIC_NUMBER;
    public System.UInt16 PACKET_REMAIN_DATA_LENGTH;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
class CM_Request_AcceptAccount : BasePacketProto
{
    public byte[] ACCOUNT_LOGIN = new byte[16];
    public byte[] ACCOUNT_PASSWORD = new byte[16];
}
```

Class that splits packets:

```
public class PacketProcessor
{
    static List<byte> raw_packet = new List<byte>();
    static int PACKET_HEADER_SIZE = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(BasePacketProto));

    static public void ProcessPacketBytes(byte[] bytes, int size)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            raw_packet.Add(bytes[i]); //Adding bytes to own storage

        if (raw_packet.Count < PACKET_HEADER_SIZE) //If we don't have enough bytes
                                                   //to build base packet, we will
                                                   //return and wait for more.
            return;

        //This packet building works fine!
        BasePacketProto bpp =
            ConvertBytesTo<BasePacketProto>(raw_packet.GetRange(
                0, PACKET_HEADER_SIZE).ToArray());

        if (raw_packet.Count >= (PACKET_HEADER_SIZE +
                                 bpp.PACKET_REMAIN_DATA_LENGTH)) //If we have enough
                                           bytes in storage to restore child packet.
        {
            switch ((ClientPacketOpcodes)bpp.PACKET_OPCODE)
            {
                case ClientPacketOpcodes.opCM_Request_AcceptAccount:
                    //But this one fails
                    bpp = ConvertBytesTo<CM_Request_AcceptAccount>(raw_packet.GetRange(
                        0, PACKET_HEADER_SIZE + bpp.PACKET_REMAIN_DATA_LENGTH).ToArray());

                    PacketHandler.Handle_opCM_Request_AcceptAccount((CM_Request_AcceptAccount)bpp);
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }

            raw_packet.RemoveRange(0, PACKET_HEADER_SIZE + bpp.PACKET_REMAIN_DATA_LENGTH);
        }
    }

    static T ConvertBytesTo<T>(byte[] data)
    {
        unsafe
        {
            fixed(byte *ptr = data)
            {
                //I am getting an access violation here when trying to
                //build child packet :(
                return (T)Marshal.PtrToStructure(new IntPtr(ptr), typeof(T));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Somewhere in the receive thread:

```
while (clientStream.CanRead)
{
    byte[] temp_buff = new byte[1024];
    int received = 0;

    while ((received = clientStream.Read(temp_buff, 0, 1024)) > 0) //Here we receive 38 bytes
    {
        //Passing it to the packet splitter.
        PacketProcessor.ProcessPacketBytes(temp_buff, received);
    }
}
```

Result when client send packet to server:

> System.AccessViolationException was not handled
>   Attempt to read or write to protected memory. Most likely it points that other memory is corrupted.

Why does it fail to convert 38 bytes to CM_Request_AcceptAccount? What should I do to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you declare a struct like

```
struct CM_Request_AcceptAccount : BasePacketProto
{
    unsigned char ACCOUNT_LOGIN[16];
    unsigned char ACCOUNT_PASSWORD[16];
};
```

in C++, the array is 'inline' and of 'fixed' length or in other words contribute 16 bytes each to the 'size' of the struct.

But in C# you are re-declaring the same struct as:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
class CM_Request_AcceptAccount : BasePacketProto
{
    public byte[] ACCOUNT_LOGIN = new byte[16];
    public byte[] ACCOUNT_PASSWORD = new byte[16];
}
```

Here, you provide no information that the first 16 bytes belong to `ACCOUNT_LOGIN` array and the next 16 to `ACCOUNT_PASSWORD`.

The line 
    byte[] ACCOUNT_LOGIN = new byte[16]

does not tell anything to the marshaller. It only causes the [CLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Runtime) to allocate a 16 byte array on the heap when an instance of `CM_Request_AcceptAccount` is created in the code.

In order to marshal the struct correctly, change the C# declaration to:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
class CM_Request_AcceptAccount : BasePacketProto
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=16)]
    public byte[] ACCOUNT_LOGIN;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=16)]
    public byte[] ACCOUNT_PASSWORD;
}
```

Additional information: Since your char arrays are meant to hold C-style string, you can also use

```
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst=16)]
public string ACCOUNT_LOGIN;
```

A point to remember here is that the marshaller will expect a null terminating character in the 16 characters you set in your C++ code.